# Google Sheets arrayfomula is not working in other column but working in another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently, I am working on a google sheet, and I put two array formulas in the sheet. One is working, and one is not. Please, anyone, help?

This formula, which I used to print the "Month" name in the column, works.
[This formula is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv1BF.jpg)

This formula where I want to print the days passed from the date Column "C" is not working; it is only working for the AA2 column and printing the same value to all other AA columns.
[This is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoBmL.jpg)

Comment: Why you are using array formula here? Put headers manually then use regular formula.

Comment: But the regular formula is not repeating itself when I enter a new record.

Comment: now solved. but facing new problem.

Comment: Put formulas to blank cells as well then it will generate results as soon as you enter data to input cells.

Comment: Hello. Harun, I ran into something else. See if you can help.
I want to color a whole row "ORANGE" if the value of a cell exceeds 6
but if the value exceeds 10 is will be "RED."
this part is easy. The track is within the colored raw there is a cell called status. if the status changes to "SHIPPED," I want all the coloring to be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell AA1 try

```
=ArrayFormula({"Days passed"; IF(LEN(C2:C), TODAY() -C2:C,)})
```

and see if that works?